# how to set auxiliary flag for 16bits binary addition

Tags: assembly, binary, addition, alu, carryflag

I know that when performing an 8-bit binary addition, the auxiliary flag is set to 1 if there is a carry from 3rd bit to 4th bit; but what about the addition of 2 16-bit numbers? i can't see any clear answer on the web.

I'm studying intel 8086 microprocessor...

For example, when i add these 2 numbers, 0x30a2 and 0xf1ac

0011 0000 1010 0010  +   1111 0001 1010 1100

```
CF=1
ZF=0
PF=1
SF=0
OF=1
AF=?
```

I'm not sure where to check it

Comment: which cpu? not all behave the same usually the 3rd to 4th bit carry flag is for BCD support.

Comment: Th _AF_ flag still only applies to carry out of the lowest nibble (lowest 4 bits). In your example the lowest nibble is 0010+1100 . Clearly there is no carry out of bit 3 so _AF_ =0.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks for your simple and straightforward answer, but check Weather Vane's answer it's in contradiction with what you say, accordin to him, the nibble is a byte(8bits)  then i should check from 1010 0010 +  1010 1100.

Comment: Weather vanes answer says "The high or low nibble *refer*s to the **LOW** order **BYTE** of a 16-bit value." . So the nibble being referred to is in the least significant byte. Nibbles are always 4 bits (not 8 bits). It basically says that no matter how many bits your register has (also applies to 32-bit) the AF flag will always be set based on carry out of the lowest nibble in the low order (least significant byte)

Comment: What is it you are really trying to accomplish? Are you trying to do BCD arithmetic? If not, the AF flag is not very useful.

Comment: I would help everyone's understanding if you stopped referring to __bit 3__ as the __3rd bit__ and to __bit 4__ as the __4th bit__. The only good wording is: __bit 3 is 4th bit__ and __bit 4 is 5th bit__.

Comment: `bit 3 is 4th bit` is overkill. I use `bit 3` (not the `3rd bit`). `Bit 3` for anyone who read the Intel references would know that `bit` numbers are 0 based starting from the least significant bit. Are you suggesting that the Intel References are also wrong? You do not see Intel say `bit 3 is 4th bit`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Intel need not say such things. It's the normal implication of the zero based numbering and it expresses the use correct use of cardinals and ordinals. Bit 0 is the first bit, ... , bit 3 is the fourth bit. You used it fine ("no carry out of bit3 so _AF_=0"), so why take it personally? My comment addresses the OP who speaks about "a carry from 3rd bit to 4th bit".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From "Programming the 8086/8088" by James W. Coffron:

> AF *auxiliary carry flag*. If this flag is set, there has been a carry
>   of the low nibble to the high nibble or a borrow from the high nibble
>   to the low. The high or low nibble refers to the low order byte of a
>   16-bit value.

In my day we would write a short piece of code to observe the processor behaviour. You could check it out by adding or subtracting two 16-bit numbers, followed by a `pushf` and `pop ax` to examine the status flags at your pleasure.

**EDIT.**

(Another way to get the flags is with `LAHF` which loads 5 bits of `AH` with flags, `AF` going to bit 4.)

So `AF` represents the carry out from bit 3 to bit 4, whatever the size of the operands.

Note that there are no branch instructions dependent on `AF`. It is used internally by the `DAA` instruction to do a decimal adjustment immediately after an `ADD` instruction, typically with `AL`.

Comment: But  Michael Petch said "The AF flag still only applies to carry out of the lowest nibble (lowest 4 bits). In your example the lowest nibble is 0010+1100 . Clearly there is no carry out of bit 3 so AF =0."

Comment: @Xsmael a nibble is four bits. The quote above says that for 16-bit arithmetic, the nibbles in question are in the low order byte. So in answer to your question, the same thing happens for a 16-bit operand as an 8-bit operand. In other words, `AF` represents the carry-out from bit 3 to bit 4 (addition), or the borrow from bit 4 to bit 3 (subtraction).

Answer (score 2):

On the 8086 the `adjust flag (bit 4)` was set when there was a carry from the 3rd to 4th bit or a borrow from the 4th to 3rd bit this is for `BCD operation support`.

`BCD operations`on the 8086 are 8 bit only and the `BCD` adjust operations only operate on the `AL` register.

For a 16 bit operation I would expect it to behave the same as if it was an 8 bit operation.

The carry flag (bit 0) is based on whether the operation is 8 or 16bit. If it is 16 bit then it will carry if the result > 65535. If it is 8 bit then it will carry if the result > 255.

Comment: Another name for the adjust flag. Which is also called the half carry flag on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

the "posititon" of the carry flag depends on the operators instruction, it will always be the highest bit

e.g. add ax,bx : since the operants are 16 bit, the carry will represent the carry of the addition of the 16th bits
even if you add ax ( with a value of 3) and 9  (these values will be treated as 0000000000000011 and 0000000000000101)

Comment: i don't know if you understood my question, i'm talking about auxiliary flag, not carry flag